# Avoiding repeating code by creating a handler class

Tags: python, class, gpio

I'm new to Python and trying to avoid repeating the same code over and over. I'm currently working with a Raspberry Pi that uses GPIO in several different classes so instead of writing

```
servoPin = 17
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(servoPin,GPIO.IN)
```

in several different classes I was hoping to bundle all the GPIO events in a PinHandler of sorts..

So, I thought of something like this for my handler class

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
 class PinHandler:
  def __init__(self):
   self.servoPin = 17
   GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
   GPIO.setup(self.servoPin,GPIO.IN)
  def getPinStatus(self,pin):
   return GPIO.input(pin)
  def addEventListener(self,functionName)
   GPIO.add_event_callback(self.servopin, functionName)
```

and then in my other classes all I have to type is

```
from pinHandler.py import PinHandler
import time

pinHandler = PinHandler()

pinHandler.addEventListener(myAwesomeFunction)

def myAwesomeFunction:
 pass
```

This would then add the callback to `myAwesomeFunction` which is outside the scope of `pinHandler`. Am I on the right track here or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Are you familiar with `inheritence`, do `class PinHandler` => `class Servo(PinHandler) ; super().__init__(17) ; self.add_event_callback(self.event_listener)` => `Servor.event_listener(...`

Comment: @stovfl i'm familiar with inheritence from java and c++. I'm not very familar with your syntax so i'm not quite sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More complete OOP design:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

class PinHandler:
    """
    Base class, wrapts all GPIO tasks
    """
    def __init__(self, pin):
        self.pin = pin
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setup(self.pin,GPIO.IN)

    def getPinStatus(self,pin):
       return GPIO.input(pin)

    def add_event_callback(self, callback)
        GPIO.add_event_callback(self.pin, callback)
```

---

```
from pinHandler.py import PinHandler


class Servo(PinHandler):
    """
    Spezialized class, handle all `Servo` related
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(17)
        self.add_event_callback(self.event_listener)

    def event_listener(self, event):
        # handle event
        pass
```

> **Usage**:

```
servo = Servo()
```